# Populate and initialize a DataTable - C#

Tags: c#, datatable

Here is my sample code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(System.DateTime));
table.Rows.Add("cat", System.DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add("dog", System.DateTime.Today);
```

I'm adding columns and rows after making my Data Table. I need to do all of this in one piece of code in DataTable Initialize, something like this:

```
new DataTable()
{
   new Columns(),
   new Rows()
};
```

is it possible?

Comment: AFAIK not. DataTable doesn't have Columns and Rows collection that you can initialize as an object initialization. OTOH there are other IEnumerable<> that would serve as in memory data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution, We can initialize a `data table` like this:

```
new DataTable
{
   Columns = { { "ID", typeof(int) } },
   Rows = { { 121 } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a static method in a class

```
    public class Table
    {
        public static DataTable GetTable()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(System.DateTime));
            table.Rows.Add("cat", System.DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add("dog", System.DateTime.Today);
            return table;
        }
    }
```